# Add footer to master page O365

Tags: office-365

How can I add a footer to a master page in Office 365 SharePoint Online site, Microsoft has recommended not to create our own master pages, so what's the solution for it now? it is urget for me, please any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best practice" is "JS injection". This is JavaScript that runs in the page.

There is lots more detail here in this excellent MVA course here:

http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/transform-sharepoint-customizations-to-sharepoint-app-model

Comment: javscript will inject that for me?

Comment: Actually JavaScript is being injected to display the footer. A call to the correct CSOM method, with the JavaScript as the argument will allow it to be invoked on every page.

Comment: thank you antelope, do you happen to have an example for that?

Answer (score 0):

- create css style sheet and add styles.
- Open the master page you are using in sharepoint designer 2013 by going to All files>catalogues>masterpage> select the masterpage you are using.html and then register it in the master.
- I followed this and it worked for me [Add footer](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/10/08/how-to-add-footer-in-sharepoint-2013-master-page/)

Comment: is this recommended to edit the master page?

Answer (score -1):

1) Open Olso.master in Edit mode

2) Select Save as action to save it as a custom master page, let's name it, lets say, helsinki.master (helsinki.master is not associated with html page, it means it could be edited directly )

3) Open helsinki.master and find DeltaPlaceHolderFooter

4) To specify custom footer, replace the block

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderFooter" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
   <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PageFooter" AllowMultipleControls="false" />
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

with

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderFooter" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
  <%--SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PageFooter" AllowMultipleControls="false" /--%>
   <div id="footer" class="noindex">
       <p style="text-align:center;">Some fancy footer is displayed here.</p>
   </div>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

Result
[image: Result]

Comment: Hi Amit, yes I know this way, but is it the recommended way now?

Comment: As someone said already, it is better to use the best practices which is JS injection in order to achieve this instead of customization of master page... however if you want something quick and dirty this would be really easy. You would have to add a schedule to update the modified Masterpage every now and then.