# SharePoint 2013 Online (365): How can I insert html tags, such as divs and footers in the OOTB master page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, master-page, css

This is my first time working with SharePoint Online and I have been asked to create a master page with some custom links inside different divs and a footer.

I saw another post [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132606/add-footer-to-master-page-o365), but it did not help me much. The link contains a video cast, but the guys there just talk and no code examples are shown. I need concrete examples how to implement this using javascript injection as I have understood it needs to be done.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to look for examples is the OfficeDev Patterns and Practices https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP, for embedding this is a sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.JavaScript

This webcast might be useful too: https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/PnP-Web-Cast-JavaScript-development-patterns-with-SharePoint

There are a lot of examples on how to embed javascript.

I personally embed jqeury and a custom javascript file on a page and do DOM manipulation using jquery.